# How to do GIT integration with UFT./QTP?

Tags: git, qtp, hp-uft

I Have cloned GIT repository into my local machine and create new test in that local path. But still I am not getting GIT commands when I right clicked on My test in UFT. Please can any one help me to get those option in UFT. Thanks in advance

UFT version: 12.51 Build 4766
GIT desktop: (3.3.4.0) 50415df

Answer (score 1):

your UFT test parent folder must have .git folder and git client must be installed and configured.

https://sumeetkushwah.com/2017/02/28/uft-git-integration/

Comment: singh, I've followed steps mentioned in the link still iam not getting git options in UFT. Installed **GITHUB** and cloned to local and created new test in same location but didnt get GIT options..

Comment: can you send me the link of your git hub repository ? I will create a test and try it.